# Popping out tuples in a list of tuples that match neighbor list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

One list of tuples reads:

```
[(5,), (4,), (7,)]
```

The second one reads:

```
[(7,'James',6,1), (3,'Don',4,3), (2,'Poppy',5,1), (4,'Dom',6,4)]
```

I wish to pop out tuples in the second list if the first element is to be found on the first list. I.e, returning the second list as follows:

```
[(3,'Don',4,3), (2,'Poppy',5,1)]
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far except formulating the problem? At least an itty bitty wee small hint of code. Try head first with for loops for start. Probably easier to get than generator expression in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [32]: list1 = [(5,), (4,), (7,)]

In [33]: list2 = [(7,'James',6,1), (3,'Don',4,3), (2,'Poppy',5,1), (4,'Dom',6,4)]

In [34]: [ x for x in list2 if x[:1] not in list1]
Out[34]: [(3, 'Don', 4, 3), (2, 'Poppy', 5, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = [(5,), (4,), (7,)]
>>> y = [(7,'James',6,1), (3,'Don',4,3), (2,'Poppy',5,1), (4,'Dom',6,4)]
>>> set_x = set(x)
>>> y[:] = [t for t in y if t[:1] not in set_x]
>>> y
[(3, 'Don', 4, 3), (2, 'Poppy', 5, 1)]
```